# How to run command using output of another command in DOS?

Tags: scripting, command, dos, if-statement

Example:

```
for /? | if (this stream has word "the" in it) {echo the line with "the"}
```

I need somehow to analyze the text in the redirected stream.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use pipes, using the vertical bar, "|".

For the example:

Pipe the output of *for* into *find*:

```
for /? | find "the"
```

First few lines of the output:

```
  command    Specifies the command to carry out for each file.
             Specifies parameters or switches for the specified command.
To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
If Command Extensions are enabled, the following additional
forms of the FOR command are supported:
    If set contains wildcards, then specifies to match against directory
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.febooti.com/products/command-line-email/batch-files/ms-dos-command-redirection.html

This website has good information on the different types of piping your can do in DOS.